# Target dependent ParseConfig

Tags: scons

I'm trying to only build a library without having all tests dependencies available,
my tests directory have it's own SConscript file that run `env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --libs --cflags libfuzzertestdependonthis')`
And if I'm building the library by specifying the lib target only, the command ParseConfig will fail because the lib is not available in my build environment

The only solutions i found are really bad:

- enclose env.ParseConfig in try expect block
- checking the command line build target content to exclude some part of the SConstruct file

I wonder if there a smart way to do this, it would be great if ParseConfig could be a handled as a source node for a specific target instead of being run immediately.

Edit:my question don't seems to be clear enough, so I will try with a better example.
When I'm building in release mode, I don't have(don't want) the libcunit required to build the tests, the issue I'm facing is that ParseConfig command is always executed regarless of the target, and in this example ParsConfig will execute `pkg-config --libs libcunit`, which will fail because this lib is not installed.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is your SCons build generating the pkg-config info? BTW ParseConfig is not a builder (and can't be), so any pkg-config info has to be present when SConscript/SConstruct is executed, and not as part of the build.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit of an odd situation - it sounds like you have a build that both generates a library, and then (in tests) uses it as if it were installed.  There will be some logistical details to work out with this. But in answer to the question, you *can* access the targets specified on the command line and make decisions based on them - see manpage entry for `COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. From your update.

If you're building in your release mode, don't call ParseConfig()..